# How to nest modules into namespaces when registering functions from C in Lua?

Tags: c, lua

I'm trying to "nest" two modules registered from C.  I'm trying to separate the concerns a bit.

Here's my "Core" module.  It has a single method called "setName"

```
int l_setName(lua_State *l)
{
    // do something
    return 0;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

static luaL_Reg const core_funcs [] =
{
    { "setName",            l_setName },
    { NULL, NULL }
};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void l_registerFuncs( lua_State * L )
{
    luaL_newlib(L, core_funcs);
    lua_setglobal(L, "Core");
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

From Lua, you can say `Core.setName("hello world")`

Here is a complicated subsystem with 20 functions that all have do with the same domain.

```
int l_importantFunction(lua_State *l)
{
    // do something
    return 0;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

static luaL_Reg const subSystem_funcs [] =
{
    { "importantFunction",          l_importantFunction },
    { NULL, NULL }
};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void l_registerFuncs( lua_State * L )
{
    luaL_newlib(L, subSystem_funcs);
    lua_setglobal(L, "Core.Subsystem");
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

I want this subsystem to be registered under Core.  I want to be able to say `Core.Subsystem.importantFunction("Hi")`

This won't work however.

What is the idiomatic lua way to do this?

After looking around at how people register "objects", it seems that this [could get very complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100435/how-do-i-create-a-class-object-in-lua-c-api-5-2).

Comment: You need to manually fetch the `Core` table and then use `lua_setfield` (or similar) to create the `Subsystem` entry in that table.

Comment: That worked! Thanks!  It's three lines of code.  I'll post it when SO lets me or if you do it first. lua_getglobal(L, "Core");
 luaL_newlib(L, subSystem_funcs);
 lua_setfield(L, -2, "SubSystem");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to manually fetch the Core table and then use lua_setfield (or similar) to create the Subsystem entry in that table.

As followed by 010110110101 the above directions became:

```
lua_getglobal(L, "Core");
luaL_newlib(L, subSystem_funcs);
lua_setfield(L, -2, "SubSystem");
```